# authentication in python script to run as root

Tags: python, pygtk

I am doing a project in Linux at system level in Python.
So that, I want to know that if i am running my code as a normal user and
if i am accessing system files then it should have root permissions for it,
then how can i prompt for root password and run further code as superuser.
I want to know that, how to run python script as superuser with password prompt for it..

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The other thing you can do is have your script automatically invoke sudo if it wasn't executed as root:

```
import os
import sys

euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    print "Script not started as root. Running sudo.."
    args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    # the next line replaces the currently-running process with the sudo
    os.execlpe('sudo', *args)

print 'Running. Your euid is', euid
```

Output:

```
Script not started as root. Running sudo..
[sudo] password for bob:
Running. Your euid is 0
```

Use `sudo -k` for testing, to clear your sudo timestamp so the next time the script is run it will require the password again.

Comment: If the application has a GUI (I am assuming as much, since the question is tagged with pygtk), gksudo should probably be used instead. The better option, however, for OSes that support it, would be to use [PolicyKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PolicyKit).

Comment: I prefer the raw exception to this elevation tactic.

Comment: I think this sort of technique is okay in the correct context. If he is creating a GUI-based installer that requires root permissions to perform certain operations, it can launch the appropriate dialog to inform the user and gain root. Take Mac OS for example, where software installation is mostly GUI-driven and most users are probably unaware the CLI exists. Raising an exception in that context isn't an option.

Comment: This solution does involve restarting the script with root permissions (as opposed to giving the same instance of the running script root permissions), lest anyone is curious.

Answer (score 6):

```
import os
euid = os.geteuid() 
if euid != 0:
  raise EnvironmentError, "need to be root"
  exit()
```

This won't prompt in the middle of script but would rather force the user to re-run it with sudo or as root

Comment: OK, i got it,but what if i want to authenticate user to run it as superuser.I don't want to give him SU priviledges withou giving password for it.Its fine i can prompt for password using above code,but how can i identify that given password is correct and if correct how can i run my further code as SU. Please take it into account that, i want to do that at runtime for normal user.

Comment: let sudo/su handle gettign the password right, check if the EUID is 0, then you'll  know it worked. @samplebias showed how to do it while continuing the same program, my answer forces the user to re-invoke the script as root