# PyQt app looks different when run via sudo

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4

I have a PyQt4 application that looks really nice when run as a normal user (on Ubuntu 12.04). But this application needs root access to bind to TCP ports below 1024, so I'm using this trick ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/5222710/95083 ) to relaunch as root if necessary.

However, when my application is run now, it looks horrible. I'm not sure what is making it look that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try gksu/gksudo instead of sudo ([Ubuntu help - about graphical sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo))