# how to read binary file with administrator privileges using strictly python in linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

So I'm trying to read a config file which needs to be "sudo'd" into but I'm trying to read its contents using python only without using terminal. when I use the code below I get the error as shown:

```
with open('/etc/motion/motion.conf','rb') as file:
 data = file.readlines()

IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/motion/motion.conf'
```

Is there anything I could try to read the contents of the file strictly with python?

Comment: Why does this configuration file _need_ to be only readable by root?

Comment: If this is the config file for [motion](http://linux.die.net/man/1/motion) the video4linux motion detection program, then you should copy the master config file `/etc/motion/motion.conf` to a hidden directory in your home directory, i.e., `~/.motion/motion.conf`, as mentioned in the `motion` docs section [Installation on Ubuntu](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/MotionGuideInstallation#A_42Installation_on_Ubuntu_42).

Answer (score 0):

`Permission denied` means that you have no permission to read that file.

If you're on Linux, you should change the file's permission use `chmod` command. Or you can use `sudo` comand run python like this:

```
sudo python filename.py
```

or login as root then run python:

```
su - root
python filename.py
```

And if you want run the program as root every times, you can use `os.execlpe()` function like this:

```
import os
import sys
euid = os.geteuid()
if euid != 0:
    args = ['sudo', sys.executable] + sys.argv + [os.environ]
    os.execlpe('sudo',*args)
with open('/etc/motion/motion.conf','rb') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
print data
```

This solution is from here:
[authentication in python script to run as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222333/authentication-in-python-script-to-run-as-root)
and is courtesy of @samplebias

Comment: So within the python file itself i cant login as root and run the file?

Comment: @the-bax I think that's impossible on Linux. But you can change the HashBang to `#!/bin/sudo python`. Then, when you use `./filename.py`, the program will ask for your password and run as root.

Comment: @the-bax Hmm, however I found [an another solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222333/authentication-in-python-script-to-run-as-root)

Comment: @KevinGuan Add the `os.execlpe('sudo',*args)` solution to your answer with a credit to samplebias

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Thank you. This is a very good solution...but why you wouldn't post another answer?

Comment: @KevinGuan You could post it as another answer but I think that it deserves to be attached to this question, as it is relevant. Edit your answer or post a new one, provide a link to the original, adapt the answer to this question and then be sure to credit `samplebias` who posted the original answer.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I've just edited my answer :). but when I test this solution I got this error: `NameError: name 'args' is not defined`

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Thanks again :P

Comment: @KevinGuan I have re-edited your question to provide a working solution and give the proper person the credit i.e. samplebias not me. It will have to pass through the review queue before others see my edit, so it may take a while.

Answer (score 0):

You should call your python file from a shell script, change the owner of this script to be root and then set the SUID bit of this script. The user will be able to run the script but the owner of the script will be root:

- http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/028.html
- http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/suid-set-suid-linuxunix.html
- etc.

Of course you must be aware of security issues that may be involved by such a thing but for local use with a simple script doing one thing, it's OK.